# How to execute graphql @relation directive for various objects

Tags: neo4j, graphql, cypher, undefined, apollo-server

I have the following typeDefs:

```
const typeDefs = `
    type Movie {
        genres: String
        movieId: Int!
        title: String
        seenBy: [User] @cypher(statement: "with $this as m match (m)<-[:RATED]-(u:User) return u")
    }

    type User {
        userId: Int!
        name: String
        seen: [Movie] @relation(name: "RATED", direction: "OUT")
        recommended(first: Int = 5): [Movie] @cypher(statement: "with $this as u match (u)-->(:Movie)<--(:User)-->(reco:Movie) where not (u)-[:RATED]->(reco) return reco, count(*) as score order by score desc limit $first")
    }

    type Query {
        movieById(movieId: Int!): Movie,
        movieBySubstring(subString: String!): [Movie]
        userById(userId: Int!): User
        userBySubstring(subString: String!): [User]
    }
`;
```

The problem are the fields on Movie and User with directives on it (seenBy, seen and recommended).
When I execute the queries movieById or userById and return only one object, the directives work fine.

However, when executing movieBySubstring or userBySubstring and return an array of objects, I get the error

> Resolve function for \"Movie.seenBy\" returned undefined

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for the problem. I had implemented custom resolvers for the movieBySubstring and userBySubstring queries and this was what caused the problem.

The solution was to use the @cypher directive in the query definition like so:

```
    type Query {
        movieById(movieId: Int!): Movie
        moviesBySubstring(subString: String!): [Movie] @cypher (statement: "match (m:Movie) where m.title contains $subString return m")
        userById(userId: Int!): User
        usersBySubstring(subString: String!): [User] @cypher (statement: "match (u:User) where u.name contains $subString return u")
    }
```

This solved the problem for me, however as I'm not experienced with cypher or neo4j I don't know if at some point this might hit limitations.